# Resize View According to Parent

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I created a custom view which is drawing circles. It takes numbers of circle from xml.

For example its generates 10 circle on whole screen.

```
<com.dd.view.MyShape
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:shape_count="10"/>
```

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.dd.view.MyShape
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:shape_count="3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But when I put this view into the smaller layout,  circle generates according view's width. I want to generate according to parent view.

I tried to override onMeasure method but I couldn’t correctly. Now It looks like :

[image]

And here my onDraw method :

```
 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int totalWidth=getMeasuredWidth();
    int major = totalWidth / circleCount;
    int radius = major/2;
    float startPoint = totalWidth / (circleCount * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < circleCount; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        else paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(startPoint + major * i, radius,radius, paint);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

In the xml, for the custom widget, make the layout_width="match_parent" rather than achieving in custom view java class, it will take parent's width.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.dd.view.MyShape
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:shape_count="3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a java solution. All I need is to find parent size

Answer (score 0):

You can get parent layout's width by,

```
View parent = (View)(this.getParent());
width = parent.getLayoutParams().width
```

For the solution of imposing parent's width(only when custom view layout_width is NOT mentioned match_parent/wrap_content) on custom view, you need to Override onMeasure().

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){

    int width = 0;

    if(getLayoutParams().width == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT){

        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    }else if(getLayoutParams().width == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT){

        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    }else{
        View parent = (View)(this.getParent());

        width = parent.getLayoutParams().width;
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width,heightMeasureSpec);
}
```